# Using NCo and ADO .NET connectors at the same time?

Tags: c#, .net, hana, sap-dotnet-connector

Is it possible to connect to SAP using NCo and ADO .NET connectors simultaneously? (of course separate connections) from within a single application?

*Actually I don't foresee issues, unless it's something SAP (purposely? or weirdly?) block/break.*

Yes done the homework, I understand what NCo is/offers and (long) understand what ADO.NET is, their purposes, obvious differences.

*I don't have the facilities to test myself (yet).*

*... I'm looking ahead for confirmation (any issues/got-ya's?) from others who do or have tried this.*

Background/reasons looking at this: (from research, other comments replies)

- NCo (read that) weak/slow retrieving bulk data, particularly from 'joined data' (parent-child and beyond) as a kicker 'joins' seem non-intuitive / easy to get wrong.
- ADO.NET for SAP [rightly] read only, but [bulk-data-retrieval] way faster!  It's sensible (it's SQL)!!

... ADO to read bulk data, NCo for single docs. (required - of course - for document update/create)

*Admission: I asked before - was closed: agree first time too much waffle and unfocused.*

I googled much, examples out there poor and do not directly address the issue.

Comment: sadly while there are people on SO that will correct spelling and even OCD warriors to correct capitalisation and punctuation seems there's seemingly none left that answer anything beyond beginner questions.
Sigh, was warned the experts had fled, wither SO.

Message received: can't speak English, White-US-English, SO doesn't want you.

Comment: it's not worth the hassle of maintaining and debugging two connections just for performance reasons, NCo is the most universal and recommended way of connecting